# Filter with Python PSAW / PRAW by hot posts and range of dates

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am doing a small project for data collection on reddit. So I am using PSAW to collect data in a certain span of time and PRAW to get the headline, comments, score, etc. I would like to know if there is any way to filter my searches by the hottest posts. A part of the code that I have is the following:

```
     # use PSAW only to get id of submissions in time interval
     gen = api.search_submissions (
         after = ts_after,
         before = ts_before,
         filter = ['id'],
         subreddit = subreddit,
         limit = limit
     )
    
     # use PRAW to get actual info and traverse comment tree
     for submission in gen:
         # use psaw here
         submission_id = submission.d _ ['id']
         # use praw from now on
         submission = reddit.submission (id = submission_id)
```